# how to handle empty value from ArrayList in baseadapter android

Tags: java, android, baseadapter

i have an ArrayList and one BaseAdapter to inflate my layout, when one array from arraylist is empty, the value on layout show text "NaN%" it is so annoying, i want handle an empty array from my arraylist with setText as (0%). so how to handle empty value from ArrayList in baseadapter android? this is my code :

```
   public class TabelNABDetail extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<NabDetail> listData;//stack
    int count;

    public TabelNABDetail(Context context, ArrayList<NabDetail>listData){
        this.context=context;
        this.listData=listData;
        this.count=listData.size();
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      return count;
        return (listData==null) ? 0 : listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view= v;
        ViewHolder holder= null;


        if(view==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_tabel_detailnab, null);
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.persen_hke1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.varpersenke1);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
            holder=(ViewHolder)view.getTag();

        }

        if (position==0) {
            holder.persen_hke1.setText("0%");


    } else {
        holder.persen_hke1.setText(String.format("%.5f",listData.get(position).getpersen_hke1())+"%");

    }
        return view;
    }

    static class ViewHolder{
        TextView ,persen_hke1;

    }
```

[image]

i want to handle if listData.get(position).getpersen_hke1() is empty value, it gonna be `holder.persen_hke1.setText("0%")` how to solve it? thanks before

Comment: In your getView if(listData == null ){
  
   return null;
  }

Comment: it still show text as NaN...

Comment: when you do "setText" on the textview you can test the content of the data you are using ex : if(listData.get(position).isGood){}else{}

Answer (score 0):

Change your getView() like this

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view= v;
    ViewHolder holder= null;

    if(view==null){
       LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_tabel_detailnab, null);
       holder=new ViewHolder();
       holder.persen_hke1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.varpersenke1);
       view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder=(ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    }

    if (position==0) {
       holder.persen_hke1.setText("0%");
    } else {
       **/////// these lines are extra lines add into your code** 

       NabDetail nabDetail = listData.get(position)
       if(!nabDetail.getpersen_hke1().equals(""))
          holder.persen_hke1.setText(String.format("%.5f",listData.get(position).getpersen_hke1())+"%");
       } else {
          holder.persen_hke1.setText("0%");
       }
    }
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Check my answer it will work properly..look at the commented lines

Comment: i got an error... no suggestion available on line  nabDetail.getpersen_hke1() != null

Comment: first it return to double, when adapter get value it will change to string with code : holder.persen_hke1.setText(String.format("%.5f",listData.get(position).getpersen_hke1())+"%");

Comment: if it is String check like this nabDetail.getpersen_hke1().equals("") look at my code it will be solve your problem..

Comment: i mean first it will return to double.... and when get value it will change to string.. its still doesn't work

Comment: change to this and then check if(!nabDetail.getpersen_hke1().equals("")) check it now.

Comment: still eror and there's notification : "Cannot invoke equals(String) on the primitive type double" if i change to if(!nabDetail.getpersen_hke1()==null) it become "no suggestion available"